# Building a flickr app on iPad

Tags: ios

i'm building an iPad application that needs to display cluster of pictures from Flickr.

Each cluster (group) can have 10 or 100 pictures. When the app starts, you can see the first 10 clusters (kinda groups of pictures, such as in the "Photos" installed application (if you pinch the group, you see the pictures inside it).

Now, my question is about performance, and how to retrieve the pictures from Flickr.
I'm considering a subset of 300.000 pictures, with approximately 2389 clusters and obviously I'm going to load only what it is needed on the screen.

When the apps start should I load all pictures included in the first 10 visible clusters ? (Please note that a cluster is represented by a bunch of ids, so the only way to display it is by stacking the included pictures, in the same way the Photos application does).

Should I use a UITableViewController for this ? I have no clue what APIs to use, I need some help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this [tutorial](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/networking/iphone-json-flickr-tutorial-part-1.html) may be of help to you.